# meaning of matrices

Tags: matrices

Update:  Using the problem statement given in a comment to an answer and formatting in LaTeX:

Let $S = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & a\end{pmatrix} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$. Is $S$ a subring of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$?

Original problem statement:  I am given a problem where I need to figure out if a 2 X 2 matrix is a subset of another.  I am given the question is this 2 X 2 matrix a subring of M (with a subscript 2 (R)).  What does the M subscript 2 stand for? Just another 2 X 2 matrix?

Comment: What does it mean for one matrix to be a subset of another matrix??

Comment: must be a subset and must be closed under subtraction and multiplication to put it simply.

Comment: D-man a matrix is an object, not a set.  Are you talking about the sub*ring* *generated* by it??

Comment: oh yes sorry about that!

Comment: subset basically states all elements of one are contained in the elements in the other

Answer (score 1):

$M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all $2\times 2$ matrices with real entries.

$S$ contains the zero matrix and the identity, so there's some hope.  Is $S$ closed under addition?
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} c & d \\ 0 & c \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a+c & b+d \\ 0 & a+c \end{pmatrix} \in S$$
Is $S$ closed under multiplication?
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} c & d \\ 0 & c \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} ac & ad+bc \\ 0 & ac \end{pmatrix} \in S$$
Checking that the relevant inverses exist is about as hard.  So $S$ is a subring of the $2 \times 2$ real matrices.

Original reply to fragmentary question:
You seem to be being asked whether a particular element of this ring is itself a subring.  Since *every* ring contains a zero element, which is unique, this can only generically be true if the single matrix is the zero matrix.  Since *every* "ring with identity $1 \neq 0$" (frequently just called a "ring" when the existence of a non-zero multiplicative identity is assumed) has at least two elements, a single element would not work (under the assumption).

Any chance there's more to the problem statement than what you have written?

Comment: Yes.  The question really is Let S = {a,b,0,a) (sorry about formatting) where a,b are in R.  Im given the question is S a subring of M2(R).

Comment: the a,b,0,a is a 2 X 2 matrix

Comment: @D-Man:  Updated your question to include your question.

Comment: I have an example but the example only says M(R).  Is M2(R) and M(R) two different things?

Comment: does this matrix have any zero divisors?

Comment: @D-Man:  This ***subring*** (or this ***set***) has zero divisors.  Try $a=0, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and square the result.  A ***matrix*** does not "have zero divisors".

Comment: alright. How would you go about proving that S is an integral domain or not?

Comment: @D-Man:  What's the definition of integral domain?

Comment: well i have that is is commutative just having trouble showing that a or b is 0 if ab=0 in S.

Comment: @D-Man:  $S$ contains zero divisors.  Try $a=0, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and square that element.